A scifi webseries 2007-2009 name starts with "E....." or "The E...."?
This is a scifi webseries, it was or still is on YOUTUBE, most likely from 2007-2009, but it could be 2006-2011 at most. The name starts with "E..." or "The E....".
"E...." is some Greek loanword, but NOT Echelon!. It's quite an unusual Greek loanword. If you can produce a list of Greek nouns that are used in English, starting with "E", that might help me as well.
Plot: 5 people wake up in the woods, all have lost their memory. They can teleport (I think). There is some sort of conspiracy stuff going on, they are gonna find out who they are, what they are doing there, or who is manipulating them and screwing them around. They are fighting some mysterious group/organisation. Main protagonist has a beard and glasses.
This was a big series, up to 20-24 episodes.
What is the name of this, it's driving me nuts.
It is NOT one of the following shows: Afterworld (web series),
    Ark (web series),
    Battlestar Galactica: Razor Flashbacks,
    Battlestar Galactica: The Face of the Enemy,
    Battlestar Galactica: The Resistance,
    Beckinfield,
    The Black Dawn,
    The Booth at the End,
    Cataclysmo and the Time Boys,
    Cell: The Web Series,
    The Crew (web series),
    Ctrl (web series),
    Edge of Normal,
    Electric City (web series),
    Galacticast,
    Gemini Division,
    H+: The Digital Series,
    Hey, Shipwreck,
    The House Between,
    Malice: The Webseries,
    The Mercury Men,
    No Warning (web series),
    Other Space,
    Pioneer One,
    Project X (web serial),
    RCVR,
    Reality On Demand,
    The Resistance (series),
    Riese: Kingdom Falling,
    The Sam Plenty Cavalcade of Action Show Plus Singing!,
    Sanctuary (TV series),
    SOLO – The Series,
    Space Janitors,
    Star Trek Continues,
    Star Trek: Hidden Frontier,
    Star Trek: Odyssey,
    Star Trek: Phase II (fan series),
    Star Trek: Phoenix,
    Star Wars: Clone Wars (2003 TV series),
    Starship Regulars,
    Tardisode,
    Time Belt,
    Transformers: Cyber Missions,
    Trenches (web series),
    Unknown Sender,
    Untitled Web Series About a Space Traveler Who Can Also Travel Through Time,
    Vincent Kosmos,
    Voyage Trekkers
I have looked from this list on Wikipedia till this one, but no joy.

You're after The Ennead, a web-series from 2009 where 5 people wake up in a forest with no memory. Ennead is an old Greek word which you can read about here. Here's the first episode:



